# Trigger Hibernate and Java App

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, triggers

I'm implementing a Java Application that does use of Hibernate for the DB management (mySQL 6.0)
A table of my database has a column that stores the the date of a future day, like 09/09/2014.
So, I'd find a way that when that day is the current day, I have to do some stuff in that table (and maybe in another one).
I was thinking to use a trigger to do that, but unfortunately I have no idea how.
Is it possible to do that, using Hibernate? Obviously, after the table changes, data in my application should be updated.
I am willing to any solution, both sides, Java and Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing a Java EE application (ie: web application served by an application server like Wildfly/JBoss AS), then you can use the EJB Scheduler. This allows you to get a business class triggered, which you can use then to get an EntityManager instance and manipulate the data that you want/need. More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

Comment: yes, I'm developing a JavaEE app, sorry I was not clear about that. And yes, I'm using also Spring. So, in this way, after the update, will I get the update data automatically, or do I need to refresh the data in my server application? 
Furthermore, why do you not suggest a trigger? is it pointless in this case?

Comment: Your data will be "fresh" on the application. The downside about using triggers is that it is probably considered part of the business logic, and as such, should be located together with the application code. But of course, there are situations where a trigger is better (for example, when you need to manipulate tons of data, and it would be too slow to do it 'outside' of the DB).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Quarts Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). It's Java API to trigger some activities on the specified time.

You can specify when to start the Scheduler. And in some function you can take the value for database and Quartz will wait for that time and then It will start the process whatever you are specifying.

[Here you can see some samples and documents](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/quick-start).

You can download the API, or its available with maven.

If you are using Spring, with that also Quartz can be used.

Comment: So, in this way, after the update, will I get the update data automatically, thanks to hibernate, or do I need to refresh the data in my server application? Furthermore, why do you not suggest a trigger?